# In testing, do we need to make the area of an acceptance region as small as possible?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, statistical-power

One criterion to access a confidence interval is that the smaller its area, the better.

For hypothesis testing, I was wondering if it is also that the smaller the area of the acceptance region, the better?

When we pursue maximum power while restricting type I error to be no more than the significance level, is the area of the resulted acceptance region usually or necessarily small(est)?

Comment: The relevant quantity for an acceptance region is its probability under the null and under specific alternatives. Could you define what you're computing when you say 'area'?

Comment: @Glen_b: "area" of a region is the Lebesgue measure of the region.

Comment: So the probability? Then that's covered in my previous comment. Type I error and Power are the complements of the probability of the acceptance region under the null and alternatives. For a given Type I error, you typically want to maximize the power (or in some situations, at a given power, you would choose to minimize the Type I error)

Comment: @Glen_b: the "area" of an acceptance region is the Lebesgue measure of the region, meaning volume or area of the region, not the probability. Consider that in confidence interval, one criterion for accessing an confidence interval is the smaller its length, the better.

Comment: What is the [measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) when dealing with the probability of acceptance?

Comment: @Glen_b: I meant Lebesgue measure of the region for measuring the volume/area/length of the region, not probability measure of the region as an event. Is acceptance region similar to confidence interval, where the smaller the length of confidence interval is, the better?

Comment: The width of the interval for an acceptance region is often semi-infinite (see one-tailed t-tests, for example), but even if it were finite, I could multiply my test statistic by an arbitrary constant to change the width of the interval of acceptance without changing *any* characteristics of the test in any way whatever - the exact same samples would remain in the acceptance region. The *relevant* measure is probability, not the (arbitrary) width of the interval.